# ¿tengo un error pero, no puedo solucionar, al cargar un excel una planilla en mvc c#?

Tags: c#, mvc, asp

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Importa todo bien los datos cuando veo en base de datos sql server, pero terminar de subir ese archivo, me resulta ese mensaje al terminar la ejecucion de importacion.

Aca esta mi codigo donde el upload procesa los archivos excel correspondiente y el index tambien.

```
private bdTiendaEntities db = new bdTiendaEntities();
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Upload(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        var marcaLista = new List<marca>();
        if (Request != null)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["UploadedFile"];
            if ((file != null) && (file.ContentLength > 0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName))
            {
                string fileName = file.FileName;
                string fileContentType = file.ContentType;
                byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                var data = file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(file.ContentLength));
                using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file.InputStream))
                {
                    ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.Commercial;
                    var currentSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets;
                    var workSheet = currentSheet.First();
                    var noOfCol = workSheet.Dimension.End.Column;
                    var noOfRow = workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                    for (int rowIterator = 2; rowIterator <= noOfRow; rowIterator++)
                    {
                        var marca = new marca();
                        marca.Codigo = Convert.ToInt32(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 1].Value);
                        marca.Nombre = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 2].Value.ToString();
                        marcaLista.Add(marca);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        using (bdTiendaEntities excelImportDBEntities = new bdTiendaEntities())
        {
            foreach (var item in marcaLista)
            {
                excelImportDBEntities.marca.Add(item);
            }
            excelImportDBEntities.SaveChanges();
        }

            return View("Index");
    }
```

Aca mi vista de marca, la cual trae los datos correspondientes, index y upload
No se si podra ser algo de que tenga valores null en la planilla, pero por lo cuales no
tengo esos valores que esten vacios.

```
    @model PagedList.IPagedList<proyectoFinal_Web.Models.marca>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "marcas", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <h2>Subir Archivo Excel</h2>
    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" id="dataFile" name="UploadedFile" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>

}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "marcas", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
        Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Codigo", "Index", new {sortOrder = ViewBag.CodigoSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            Nombre
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Codigo)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombre)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Codigo }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Codigo }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Codigo })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<br />
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
    new { page, marcas = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))

public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.CodigoSortParm = sortOrder == "codigo_asc" ? "codigo_desc" : "codigo_asc";
        ViewBag.NombreSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "nombre_desc" : "";

        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }

        var marcas = from m in db.marca  //LINQ
                       select m;

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            marcas = marcas.Where(m => m.Nombre.Contains(searchString));
        }

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "codigo_desc":
                marcas = marcas.OrderByDescending(m => m.Codigo);
                break;
            case "codigo_asc":
                marcas = marcas.OrderBy(m => m.Codigo);
                break;
            case "nombre_desc":
                marcas = marcas.OrderByDescending(m => m.Nombre);
                break;
            default:
                marcas = marcas.OrderBy(m => m.Nombre);
                break;
        }

        int pageSize = 20;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(marcas.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
      //  return View(marcas.ToList());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

segun lo publicado se debe a que cuando cargar el archivo y lo guardas, regresas a la view pero al view esta esperando el modelo de marcar, el cual nunca regresas.

antes de hacer el view tendrias que hacer una consulta a la tabla de marcas y enviarla a la view

ejemplo

```
return View("Index",db.Marcas.tolist());
```

Comment: Ah vale pa gracias

Comment: por ejemplo seria algo asi la consulta?; var marcas = from m in db.marca  //LINQ
                           select m;

Answer (score 0):

[![[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0hZT.png][1]][1]

ese error me sale si agrego ese return

```
return View("Index",db.Marcas.tolist());
```

Comment: Saludos, esto no debería ser una respuesta. Por favor, edita la pregunta para añadir esta información. Las respuestas solo deben ser usadas para responder a las preguntas.